# How can I add an element to an array with the index number "array[number of items in array + 1]"

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I'm trying to write a program which allows the user to add an element to an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    string words[] = {"apple", "bear", "cards"};
    
    string s = get_string("New word:");
    
    s = words[(sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0])) + 1];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
}
```

It was my intention to add the element to the array as index number `words[number of items in words + 1]`, but I receive the error message `error: array index 4 is past the end of the array (which contains 3 elements) [-Werror,-Warray-bounds]`.

Comment: Either over allocate space in your array, or learn to use `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` as appropriate.

Comment: Once an array is declared its size cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over allocate `words` array:

```
#define MAX_WORDS 10

static int LoadPredefinedWords(string words, string preDefined) {...}

const string predefinedWords = {"apple", "bear", "cards", NULL};
string words[MAX_WORDS] = {NULL};

int NumberOfWords = LoadPredefinedWords(words, predefinedWords);

for(int i = NumberOfWords; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) ...
```

Or learn to use `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`, for which you can find documentation included with your compiler or online.

You could just take a shortcut:

```
#define MAX_WORDS 10

string words[MAX_WORDS] = {"apple", "bear", "cards", NULL};;

int NumberOfWords = 3;

for(int i = NumberOfWords; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) ...
```

But at some point you need to learn about iterating over NULL terminated arrays of pointers. We tend to mark the ends of things in C with a zero value. A string is just a `char *`, where the end of character sequence is marked by a `\0`, aka; null, and not be confused with `NULL` which is often defined as something like `#define NULL void*`.

So there's a better version that is less likely to have bugs due to arithmetic errors:

```
pArrayEnd = words + NumberOfWords;
for (string *pIterator = words; pIterator < pArrayEnd; pIterator++) ...
```

---

Bookmark [this page for future reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Read it from top to bottom once (maybe in several sittings), then spend 20 minutes per day studying it. Don't get caught up trying to understand every nuance, just absorb it while you're going off and writing toy programs.

Bookmark these as well:

- http://code-reference.com/c
- http://c-faq.com/
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/idx/headers.html

Comment: Hi jwdonahue, but won't this mean that `words[number of items in words + 1]` = `words[MAX_WORDS + 1]` = `words[11]`?

Comment: That is an excellent question! Number of items in words is the number of non-NULL string pointers in the array, which can be counted in a loop and set in your program. You don't currently have a number of items anything in your program. I know you're just learning C, so I am not going to just throw a whole solution at you. You'll learn faster and better if you answer as many of your own questions as possible.

Comment: surely the loop condition should be `MAX_WORDS`, not dividing by sizeof

Comment: @M.M, yup, sorry, I cut and pasted the OP's code and didn't look close enough, nice catch. And I did it twice! Moving too fast.

Comment: Thanks @jwdonahue, this is a lot to take in, I'll do some googling at try to figure out what it all means.

Comment: @BlueKhakis, CS50 is not a great platform to learn C. Their libraries try to hide details from you that you should learn very early on. For starters, there is no such thing a string type in C, only the convention that `char array[]` can be initialized with a string literal `"any string"` that includes a null character at the end of it. It's one of the first details you can learn from the classic HelloWorld program.

Comment: You will find lots of examples of using `realloc` here at SO. Your CS50 course probably covers it eventually.

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't realise that about strings. Yeah- I'm trying to figure out how to use `malloc` and `realloc` right now, but every description just seems to introduce more jargon that I don't know.

Comment: Learn to ask the Google "what is <jargon>", but can be a rabbit hole, so drill down into the result a little ways, and then move on. Just write a program that uses `malloc` to allocate enough space to store a few string pointers and then use `realloc` to expand it as needed. You'll learn more writing tiny programs, exploring each new thing. Learn to use your debugger!

Comment: You're going to need that `LoadPredefinedWords()` function I suggested earlier btw. And when you run into trouble with that new approach, search first, then create a new question here at SO if you don't find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @jwdonahue . I've decided to go down the rabbit hole as you suggest and just google each new term I come across, hopefully I should hit bedrock somewhere and then build up from there.

Comment: @BlueKhakis, Okay, I added some links at the bottom of my answer, for you to bookmark. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228240/discussion-between-bluekhakis-and-jwdonahue).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to create a dynamic array for such task.

Your array right now has a stable, constant size and cannot be changed. So it's not so simple just to add +1 element to the final structure.

Or in another case - you can create an array of bigger size and create a variable for storing the current amount of elements in your array. But it's a bad solution for cases when you need to do a random amount of "+1" operations.

Comment: Hi Emma, I am honoured to have received your first answer to a question! I'm quite new to programming, how would I go about creating a dynamic array?